# Maven artifact zipped jars

Tags: maven, maven-dependency-plugin

I have a maven artifacts in Zip format that contains necessary jars to compile my project.

I tried using unpack-dependencies goal but seems like Mavan does not pick jars as dependencies.

```
Is it doable to use jars withing a zip artifact to compile the project?
These jars are not  associated its own group id or artifact id
```

Comment: Why do you have artifacts packed into a zip file and not in a Maven repository?

Comment: @khmarbaise final artifact is on Nexus as a ZIP. But project needs jars inside it.

Comment: Why as a zip? Usually you build artifacts and store them as jars into the repository (Nexus). As you already tried to use unpack-dependencies you have recognized that they will not be used as deps. So the only way I see is to change the original project and deploy the artifacts as jars (which i assume being done already) and finally use them.

Comment: @khmarbaise unfortunately the ZIP artifact is 3rparty product so unable to  decompose and put to nexus. Is there anyway that could add these jars as dependencies, at lease as a system path?

Comment: You can't decompress the zip and deploy the jars you need into into Nexus? You can try to go the way using `<scope>system</scope>` but i can't recommend it.